phpstan: assign.readOnlyProperty
The following class
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use stdClass;

class Payload
{
    private(set) readonly array $validation;
    
    private array $ids = [];


    public function __construct(private readonly stdClass $payload)
    {
        $this->parseValidation();
    }

    private function parseValidation(): void
    {
        $validations = [];

        foreach ($this->payload->validation as $validation) {

            $validations[] = [
                'id' => Str::orderedUuid()->toString(),
                'field_id' => $this->ids[$validation->field_id],
                'rule' => $validation->rule,
                'value' => $this->validationValue($validation->value),
                'message' => $validation->message,
            ];
        }

        $this->validation = $validations;
    }

    private function validationValue(mixed $value): mixed
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->ids[$value] ?? $value;
    }
}

when analysed returns
$ phpstan analyse app/Payload.php
 1/1 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%

 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Line   Payload.php
 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------
  35     Readonly property App\Payload::$validation is already assigned.
           assign.readOnlyProperty
 ------ -----------------------------------------------------------------

It appears the issue is with the call to validationValue method, but cannot figure out what and why read only association error?

It looks like PHPStan doesn't consider that code to be in the constructor. Might also have to do with you using an older version of PHPStan, as the error I get on the live site is not the same.

Here's the link to playground https://phpstan.org/r/1ffd3442-4364-454a-8f73-e9539c5a1899

Yes, and if you move the contents of the parseValidation() function into the constructor, the error goes away. So it seems this is a PHPStan bug. You could try reporting it or just move the code into the constructor since it can only be called from there anyway.

It's been marked as an actual bug by phpstan

"added this to the 'Easy fixes' milesone" Bonus!
